# Code returns XML and html of page as well

Tags: asp.net, xml, excel, streamwriter

On a asp.net page I call the following function to output some data as XML to be downloaded as a spreadsheet.

```
public static void ToExcelStream(DataSet dsInput, string filename, string ProductName)

{
    string excelXml = GetExcelXml(dsInput, filename, ProductName);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "utf-8";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");


    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename));
    sw.Write(excelXml);
    sw.Close();
    sw.Dispose();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(filename);
}
```

excelXml contains the XML to be used as the basis for the spreadsheet. The XML returned by the GetExcelXml function is correctly formed. If you break the code, save the XML as a .xls file - it opens perfectly in Excel.

But, my problem is that the code above generates a file which contains the XML and, after the XML, all the html of the calling page is included too. Why is the html of the calling page being added after the XML being returned by the GetExcelXml function?

The downloaded file starts ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

the xml ends with ...

```
</Worksheet>\r\n</Workbook>
```

but, then, straight after is ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//WCD//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
<html>
<head>
all the script references for the page, title etc. are in here
</head>
<body>
all the html for the body appears here
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the html for the page being appended to the XML?

Comment: Are there any chances filename already is a file that has HTML in it, and you're just appending the XML?

Comment: No, the filename is created on the fly using a random string generator, which is then passed to the ToExcelStream function.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(filename);
```

to:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename));
```